# {exp:number_format} not working on some pages

Tags: number-format

I have a snippet

```
{exp:number_format number="{price}" decimals="2"  dec_point="." thousands_sep=","}
I use this snippet in two pages.
```

The weird thing about this is that in one page, it outputs correctly while in the other one does not.

For example, I passed 19000.00 in both of them.

In one page, I get 19000.00 but in the other one I got 0.00

UPDATE:

Ok I noticed that in the problem page, I am using Switchee while in the working page, I don't.

I tried changing the problem page to not use Switchee and it worked.

Does this mean that this is somewhat a parse order problem?

UPDATE 2:

Here is the sample code

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}
        {case value="#some regex expressions here#"}
            {exp:low_search:results 
            limit="10"
            channel="foo"
            paginate="bottom"
            status="open"
            parse="inward"}
        {/case}
        {case default="Yes"}
            {exp:low_search:results 
            query="{segment_2}"
            limit="10"
            channel="foo"
            paginate="bottom"
            status="open"
            parse="inward"}
        {/case}
    {/exp:switchee}
        ........
        <h2>{snippet.that.contains.the.number.format.code}</h2>
        ........
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

Here is the snippet code

```
${exp:number_format number="{price}" decimals="2"  dec_point="." thousands_sep=","}
```

UPDATE 3:

I tried changing

```
 ${exp:number_format number="{price}" decimals="2"  dec_point="." thousands_sep=","}
```

to

```
${exp:number_format decimals="2"  dec_point="." thousands_sep="," parse="inward"}{price}{/exp:number_format}
```

in hopes of solving the problem. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

P.S.

For all intents and purposes, {exp:low_search:results} is functionally the same as {exp:channel:entries}

Comment: Are you using the switchee tag with "parse=inward" ?

Comment: Yes, I am using it

Comment: Yes, likely a parse order, can u throw up some simplified code so we can see where variables are being declared etc.

Comment: I updated my question to include simplified code

Comment: What's the primary difference between the 2 switchee cases ? Not being a Grand Master of parse orders and what not, I'd personally look at capturing the different variables required and move your opening {exp:low:results} tag outside the switchee then pass the variables to the {low:results}.

Comment: Why is the closing `{/exp:low_search:results}` tag outside of the **switchee** case? Most likely you will need to contain all groups of code within each case for this to work properly

Comment: The purpose of the case in switchee is to make the opening tag dynamic. If I follow your suggestion, I would violating the DRY principle.

Comment: Siebird is right, having opening tags inside a switchee and closing tag outside will cause more grief then good and prove problematic when trying to debug. I'd defiantly look at an embed and pass a variable to the embed.

Comment: Also, you have two different opening tags `{exp:results}` & `{exp:low_search:results}`. Not sure if that is a typo?

Comment: @Siebird Yeah, it is definitely a typo.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a guide then a solution, experimentation is your friend.

```
{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}
        {case value="my case value"}
            {stash:query}all{/stash:query}
        {/case}
        {case default="Yes"}
            {stash:query}{segment_2}{/stash:query}
        {/case}
    {/exp:switchee}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Further down the template, ese the stash'ed variable holding the variable defined above as the query.

```
 {exp:low_search:results 
    query="{exp:stash:query}" // Whack the stash Var in here
    limit="10"
    channel="foo"
    paginate="bottom"
    status="open"
    parse="inward"}

      <h2>{snippet.that.contains.the.number.format.code}</h2>

  {/exp:low_search:results}
```

PS. You will need to install [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash) obviously :)

Comment: Unfortunately, using stash is not an option. The code structure that I have is necessary because of stash parse order problems,

Comment: Then without any further knowledge of how your code is wrapped, I'd look at embeds (stash or EE) between your case arguments. Its not the dryest solution but there appears to be more in play then you've outlined.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I really believe your issue is with have the closing tag outside of the switchee cases. You can completely remove Switchee and use a simple conditional to show/hide the `query` parameter since it only seems to be on a unique case.

```
{exp:low_search:results 
  {if segment_2 != "something"}query="{segment_2}"{/if}
  limit="10"
  channel="foo"
  paginate="bottom"
  status="open"
  parse="inward"
}
```

#### Update

What if you nested Switchee in between the `{exp:low_search:results}`:

```
{exp:low_search:results 
    {exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}
        {case value="#some regex expressions here#"}
            limit="10"
            channel="foo"
            paginate="bottom"
            status="open"
        {/case}
        {case default="Yes"}
            query="{segment_2}"
            limit="10"
            channel="foo"
            paginate="bottom"
            status="open"
        {/case}
    {/exp:switchee}
}
```

Comment: I can't use native if else since the value that I am comparing to segment_2 are regex expressions

Comment: Updated my answer to nest switchee between the opening tag

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work. I guess it might be that params parse order is different?

Comment: I just realized I still had `parse=inward` in there. Try it without that parameter